# A collective term describing both pick-up and drop-off?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, synonyms

I am looking for a single term that describes both `dropping off` and `picking up` terms.

For example, a bus stop can be of three types(for any particular bus company)

1. Pickup only
2. Drop off only
3. Pickup and drop off both

So, is there a single term that may use to describe above 3 terms?

Comment: There are drop-off-only, pick-up-only and *normal* ***bus stops***

Comment: What is the actual context?  Is it  buses, or was that just a convenient example that came to mind?  Are you looking for an overarching abstract term that is context-independent, as your name suggests?

Comment: The term that covers all three possibilities is a 'stop'. When the vehicle is not in motion, any combination of pick-ups drop-offs and anything in between may occur. When the bus stops moving, these things can happen.

Answer (score 5):

General words for "pick up" and "drop off" and "both" are ***transportation*** and ***delivery***. Generally, they imply all three. The word ***transfer*** can also be used to convey both meanings by themselves or simultaneously.

> We can meet at the **transfer** station, don't forget the packages or
>   yourselves.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/transportation

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/delivery

Comment: thanks; I'll accept "transfer" as I have also been thinking of this term, but was looking for a perfect term; +1 for u

Answer (score 0):

The term that covers all three possibilities is a '**stop**'. When the vehicle is not in motion, any combination of pick-ups drop-offs and anything in between may occur. When the bus stops moving, these things can happen.

Answer (score 0):

Australian authorities call it a "**kiss and ride**" zone. 
https://www.service.nsw.gov.au/transaction/kiss-and-ride-zones